# Fit only the height on a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

I've been trying to get the `fit` key in TikZ to scale a node so that it matches only the height of it's fit nodes but I haven't been successful. I'm trying to get the red box to be the size of the blue boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\newcommand{\filler}[1]{\begin{minipage}{12cm}\small\lipsum[#1]\end{minipage}}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,outer sep = 2pt, text centered]
\tikzstyle{box}=[rectangle,draw,inner sep=0em]

\tikzstyle{vline}=[box, rotate=90, fill=red!20, minimum height=1cm]
\tikzstyle{hline}=[box, fill=blue!20, minimum width=10cm]

\node[vline] (a) at (0,0) {\textbf{How do I extend this node to fit?}};
\node[hline] (b1) [below right = of a.south east] {\filler{1}};
\node[hline] (b2) [below = of b1] {\filler{2}};
\node[hline] (b3) [below = of b2] {\filler{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Question:** for node `a`, how do I keep the x dimension fixed, while the y dimension scales to the height of nodes `(b1,b2,b3)`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly what you want to fit?

Comment: If you want to have the box hug the text in node `a`, you can write `minimum height=0pt`

Comment: @PeterGrill I've updated the picture to indicate what I'm trying to do, is it clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\newcommand{\filler}[1]{\small\lipsum[#1]}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2pt,align = justify]
\tikzset{
box/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=0em},
vline/.style={box, fill=red!20, align=center},
hline/.style={box, fill=blue!20, text width=12cm}
}

\node[hline] (b1) {\filler{1}};
\node[hline] (b2) [below = of b1] {\filler{2}};
\node[hline] (b3) [below = of b2] {\filler{3}};

\coordinate [left=12pt of b1.north west] (top);
\coordinate [left=12pt of b3.south west] (bottom);

\node[vline, minimum width=10pt,fit=(top)(bottom), 
    label={[rotate=90]center:\textbf{How do I extend this node to fit?}}] (a) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Summary

- I removed `minipage` environment from your `\filler` macro and replaced `text centered` with `text justified` in your `tikzpicture` options as this does the same effect.
- I replaced `node distance=0pt` with `node distance=2pt`.
- Two `coordinates`: `top` and `bottom` were defined so for use with the `fit` option for the node `a`. Now, instead of positioning `b1` in terms of node `a`, node `a` was positioned in terms of nodes `b1` and `b3` using `fit` library. **Update**: It is enough to use two `coordinates` for the `fit` as the node `(a)` will simply create a bounding box around the two coordinates and any coordinate defined between these two points. As long as the coordinates are aligned, there is no harm in doing this as coordinates are theoretically dimensionless. And, for the `10pt` width of the node `(a)`, I thought that was what you were after; if not, you can change it to a dimension that you like `:)`
- The work-around for rotating the text of node `a` is done with the `label` option. **Update**: The work-around is needed, since with this solution, doing `rotate=90` directly in the node option will rotate both the node shape and the text.

### Update

- I have replaced the old `\tikzstyle` with `\tikzset` as in Gonzalo's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, they are greatly appreciated! A few questions about your answer if you don't mind: 1] Why is a work-around for rotating text needed? 2] Was the 12pt padding just an aesthetic choice? 3] How does fit work in this case when you only give two coordinates... which way does it grow?

Comment: @Hooked See my update.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another option without using the `fit` library or additional coordinates. I used the `let` syntax to calculate the necessary length for the node; I also changed the old `\tikzstyle` syntax for the newer `\tikzset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\filler}[1]{{\small\lipsum[#1]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2pt,align=justify]
\tikzset{
box/.style={rectangle,draw},
vline/.style={box, fill=red!20,align=center,minimum height=1cm,rotate=90},
hline/.style={box, fill=blue!20, text width=12cm}
}

\node[hline] (b1) {\filler{1}};
\node[hline] (b2) [below = of b1] {\filler{2}};
\node[hline] (b3) [below = of b2] {\filler{3}};

\path let \p1 = (b1.north), \p2 = (b3.south) in 
  node[vline,inner xsep=0pt,text width=\y1-\y2-\pgflinewidth,anchor=south east] 
  at ([xshift=-2pt]b1.north west) {some text here};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. It also uses `fit` tikzlibrary but there's no need for additional `coordinates` or `calc` tikzlibrary.

```
\node[vline, minimum width=1cm,
    fit=(b1.north)(b3.south), 
    label={[rotate=90]center:\textbf{How do I extend this node to fit?}}, 
    left=of b1.north west, anchor=north east] (a) {};
```

declares a node which height includes `b1.north` and `b3.south` and is placed with its top right corner (`anchor=north east`) at `node distance` from `b1.north west`. It's important to declare `anchor` after `left=of` because this last option fixes anchor to `east`.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\newcommand{\filler}[1]{\small\lipsum[#1]}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2pt,align = justify]
\tikzset{
box/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=0em},
vline/.style={box, fill=red!20, align=center},
hline/.style={box, fill=blue!20, text width=12cm}
}

\node[hline] (b1) {\filler{1}};
\node[hline] (b2) [below = of b1] {\filler{2}};
\node[hline] (b3) [below = of b2] {\filler{3}};

%\coordinate [left=12pt of b1.north west] (top);
%\coordinate [left=12pt of b3.south west] (bottom);

\node[vline, minimum width=10pt, 
    fit=(b1.north)(b3.south), 
    label={[rotate=90]center:\textbf{How do I extend this node to fit?}}, 
    left=of b1.north west, anchor=north east, minimum width=1cm ] (a) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]