How to adjust the height of an image to the distance between two nodes
I am trying to set the height of a photo to the height of a node. The code is:
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}   % There are issues with some babel packages
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    % Computing some coordinates 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
%
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.pathreplacing, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\colorlet{notblue}{Blue!90!Gray!65!white}
\colorlet{notred}{Red!85!Orange}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{correo/}}


\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{grffile}
\graphicspath{{../0_Graficos/Diapositiva_2/}}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1,
    every node/.style={font=\huge,  },
    circ1/.style={scale=1.1,
    draw,circle, line width=0.8mm, fill=white, minimum width=1.1cm,
    font=\Huge ,}, %\bfseries
    blockV/.style={draw=cyan, thick, fill=cyan!50, rounded corners,text =black,
        minimum width=15em,
        minimum height=4.2em,
        font = \huge ,
        outer sep=0pt, align=center, rotate=90} ,
    vhilit/.style={draw=blue!60, line width=0.8mm, , inner sep=2em},
    ]
    \sffamily   
    % Help lines
    % \draw[help lines, gray!30] (-1,-1) grid (34,28);
    % at ([xshift=-20pt]AI.north west)
    
    % From the bottom
    % 6
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (R6) at (28,3) {\includegraphics[height=1.2cm, width=4.5cm,angle=10]{6_baliza.png} };
    \node[align=center, text width=5cm, scale=0.95, below = 0.1cm of R6] (R6txt) 
                                                                  {Industrial light beacon BR50}; 
        
    %----
    % 4-5
    \node[align=center, text width=4cm, scale=0.95, ] (R4txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,2cm)}]R6.north west) 
                                                                  {Fan HJM\\HM-4500};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = -0.1cm of R4txt.north] (R4) {\includegraphics[height=3.75cm, ]{4_ven2.jpg} };
    
    \node[align=center, text width=4cm, scale=0.95, ] (R5txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,2cm)}]R6.north east) 
                                                                %([shift={(3cm,0cm)}]R4txt.east) 
                                                                 {CDPR\\end-effector};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.1cm of R5txt.north] (R5) {\includegraphics[height=3.5cm, ]{5_cdpr_endeffector.png} };
    
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (wind) at ($(R4.east)!0.45!(R5.west)$) {\includegraphics[height=1.8cm, ]{4x_wind.png} };
    
    \node[circ1] (C4) at ([shift={(0.75cm,3.25cm)}]R4txt.north west) {\bf 4};
    \node[circ1] (C5) at ([shift={(-0.75cm,3.25cm)}]R5txt.north east) {\bf 5};
    
    \node[circ1] (C6) at ([shift={(0cm,-6.4cm)}]C4) {\bf 6};  
    %----
    % 3
    \node[align=center, text width=8cm, scale=0.95, ] (R3txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,10.3cm)}]R6txt.north) 
                                                            {Industrial servomotor\\AM 8112};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.cm of R3txt.north] (R3) {\includegraphics[height=2.75cm, ]{3_servomotor.png} };
    \node[circ1] (C3) at ([shift={(0cm,5cm)}]C4) {\bf 3};
    %----
    % 2
    \node[align=center, text width=8cm, scale=0.95, ] (R2txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,4.3cm)}]R3txt.north) 
                                                            {Industrial controller\\CX 5130};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.1cm of R2txt.north] (R2) {\includegraphics[height=2.2cm, ]{2_controlador.png} };
    \node[circ1] (C2) at ([shift={(0cm,5cm)}]C3) {\bf 2};
    
    %----
    % 1
    \node[align=center, text width=8cm, scale=0.95, ] (R1txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,4.3cm)}]R2txt.north) 
                                                            {Intel RealSense D435i};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.1cm of R1txt.north] (R1) {\includegraphics[height=2.5cm, ]{1_camera.png} };
    \node[circ1] (C1) at ([shift={(0cm,5cm)}]C2) {\bf 1};
    
    %------------------------------------
    \node[draw, vhilit, fit= (C1) (R1txt) (C5) (R6txt) (C6)] (DPART) {};
    %------------------------------------
    %------------------------------------
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105975/178274
    
    \path let \p1 = (DPART.north), \p2=(DPART.south) in
        node[,  inner sep=0pt, text width=\y1-\y2-\pgflinewidth, anchor=north east] (TOT)
        at ([xshift=-4.5cm]DPART.north west)  {\includegraphics[height=26.78cm, trim={0 0 4.75cm 0},clip]{CDPR.png} } ;
    
    
    \begin{scope}[x={(TOT.south east)},y={(TOT.north west)}]
        \node[circ1] at (1.1,0.5) {\bf 1};
        \node[circ1] at (1.115,0.08) {\bf 3};
        \node[circ1] at (0.65,0.55) {\bf 5};
        \node[circ1] at (-0.3,0.2) {\bf 6};
        \node[circ1] at (-0.01,0.725) {\bf 4};
    \end{scope}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I have tested the solution in Fit only the height on a node with image CDPR.png with:
\path let \p1 = (DPART.north), \p2=(DPART.south) in
            node[,  inner sep=0pt, text width=\y1-\y2-\pgflinewidth, anchor=north east] (TOT)
            at ([xshift=-4.5cm]DPART.north west)  {\includegraphics[height=26.78cm, trim={0 0 4.75cm 0},clip]{CDPR.png} } ;

but I have to adjust manually the height of the figure to fit to the bottom left corner of the frame at the right (node DPART) setting height=26.78cm. I also do not know why the circ1 nodes on the image have negative coordinates into the scope:
    \begin{scope}[x={(TOT.south east)},y={(TOT.north west)}]
        \node[circ1] at (1.1,0.5) {\bf 1};
        \node[circ1] at (1.115,0.08) {\bf 3};
        \node[circ1] at (0.65,0.55) {\bf 5};
        \node[circ1] at (-0.3,0.2) {\bf 6};
        \node[circ1] at (-0.01,0.725) {\bf 4};
    \end{scope}

e.g. \node[circ1] at (-0.3,0.2) {\bf 6};
EDIT:
MWE using example-image-a
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage    {tikz}
% \usepackage    {siunitx} % SI units, \SI and \ang commands
% \usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}   % There are issues with some babel packages
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    % Computing some coordinates 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
%
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.pathreplacing, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}


\colorlet{notblue}{Blue!90!Gray!65!white}
\colorlet{notred}{Red!85!Orange}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{correo/}}


\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{grffile}
\graphicspath{{../0_Graficos_Vigo/Diapositiva_2/}}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1,
    every node/.style={font=\huge,  },
    circ1/.style={scale=1.1,
    draw,circle, line width=0.8mm, fill=white, minimum width=1.1cm,
    font=\Huge ,}, %\bfseries
    blockV/.style={draw=cyan, thick, fill=cyan!50, rounded corners,text =black,
        minimum width=15em,
        minimum height=4.2em,
        font = \huge ,
        outer sep=0pt, align=center, rotate=90} ,
    vhilit/.style={draw=blue!60, line width=0.8mm, , inner sep=2em},
    ]
    \sffamily   
    % Help lines
    % \draw[help lines, gray!30] (-1,-1) grid (34,28);
    
    % From the bottom
    % 6
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (R6) at (28,3) {\includegraphics[height=1.2cm, width=4.5cm,angle=10]{example-image-a} };
    \node[align=center, text width=5cm, scale=0.95, below = 0.1cm of R6] (R6txt) %at ([yshift=-.5cm]R6.south) 
                                                                  {Industrial light beacon BR50}; 
        
    %----
    % 4-5
    \node[align=center, text width=4cm, scale=0.95, ] (R4txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,2cm)}]R6.north west) 
                                                                  {Fan HJM\\HM-4500};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = -0.1cm of R4txt.north] (R4) {\includegraphics[height=3.75cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    
    \node[align=center, text width=4cm, scale=0.95, ] (R5txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,2cm)}]R6.north east) 
                                                                %([shift={(3cm,0cm)}]R4txt.east) 
                                                                 {CDPR\\end-effector};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.1cm of R5txt.north] (R5) {\includegraphics[height=3.5cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (wind) at ($(R4.east)!0.45!(R5.west)$) {\includegraphics[height=1.8cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    
    \node[circ1] (C4) at ([shift={(0.75cm,3.25cm)}]R4txt.north west) {\bf 4};
    \node[circ1] (C5) at ([shift={(-0.75cm,3.25cm)}]R5txt.north east) {\bf 5};
    
    \node[circ1] (C6) at ([shift={(0cm,-6.4cm)}]C4) {\bf 6};  % <-----
    %----
    % 3
    \node[align=center, text width=8cm, scale=0.95, ] (R3txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,10.3cm)}]R6txt.north) 
                                                            {Industrial servomotor\\AM 8112};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.cm of R3txt.north] (R3) {\includegraphics[height=2.75cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    \node[circ1] (C3) at ([shift={(0cm,5cm)}]C4) {\bf 3};
    %----
    % 2
    \node[align=center, text width=8cm, scale=0.95, ] (R2txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,4.3cm)}]R3txt.north) 
                                                            {Industrial controller\\CX 5130};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.1cm of R2txt.north] (R2) {\includegraphics[height=2.2cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    \node[circ1] (C2) at ([shift={(0cm,5cm)}]C3) {\bf 2};
    
    %----
    % 1
    \node[align=center, text width=8cm, scale=0.95, ] (R1txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,4.3cm)}]R2txt.north) 
                                                            {Intel RealSense D435i};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.1cm of R1txt.north] (R1) {\includegraphics[height=2.5cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    \node[circ1] (C1) at ([shift={(0cm,5cm)}]C2) {\bf 1};
    
    %------------------------------------
    \node[draw, vhilit, fit= (C1) (R1txt) (C5) (R6txt) (C6)] (DPART) {};
    %------------------------------------
    %------------------------------------
    
    \path let \p1 = (DPART.north), \p2=(DPART.south) in
        node[,  inner sep=0pt, text width=\y1-\y2-\pgflinewidth, anchor=north east] (TOT)
        at ([xshift=-4.5cm]DPART.north west)  {\includegraphics[height=26.78cm, trim={0 0 1.5cm 0},clip]{example-image-a} } ;
    
    
    \begin{scope}[x={(TOT.south east)},y={(TOT.north west)}]
        \node[circ1] at (1.1,0.5) {\bf 1};
        \node[circ1] at (1.115,0.08) {\bf 3};
        \node[circ1] at (0.65,0.55) {\bf 5};
        \node[circ1] at (-0.3,0.2) {\bf 6};
        \node[circ1] at (-0.01,0.725) {\bf 4};
    \end{scope}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

    \end{document}

(Note that the trim applied at the right of the image is now 1.5cm.

Here's a starting point that you'll need to finalise.  In order to align the edges of the photo and the right-hand insert, I've removed the inner sep=2em parameter in the style   vhilit/.style={draw=blue!60, line width=0.8mm, %inner sep=2em%<--------------. This removes the white space around the right-hand insert.
\path let \p1 = (DPART.north), 
            \p2=(DPART.south),
            \n1={veclen(\y1,\y2)},
            \n2={\n1-.8mm}
in
    node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
    anchor=east] (TOT)
    at (DPART.west)  {\includegraphics[height=\n2]{example-image-a} } ;


\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage    {tikz}
% \usepackage    {siunitx} % SI units, \SI and \ang commands
% \usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}   % There are issues with some babel packages
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    % Computing some coordinates 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
%
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.pathreplacing, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}


\colorlet{notblue}{Blue!90!Gray!65!white}
\colorlet{notred}{Red!85!Orange}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{correo/}}


\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{grffile}
\graphicspath{{../0_Graficos_Vigo/Diapositiva_2/}}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1,
    every node/.style={font=\huge,  },
    circ1/.style={scale=1.1,
    draw,circle, line width=0.8mm, fill=white, minimum width=1.1cm,
    font=\Huge ,}, %\bfseries
    blockV/.style={draw=cyan, thick, fill=cyan!50, rounded corners,text =black,
        minimum width=15em,
        minimum height=4.2em,
        font = \huge ,
        outer sep=0pt, align=center, rotate=90} ,
    vhilit/.style={draw=blue!60, line width=0.8mm, %inner sep=2em
    },
    ]
    \sffamily   
    % Help lines
    % \draw[help lines, gray!30] (-1,-1) grid (34,28);
    
    % From the bottom
    % 6
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (R6) at (28,3) {\includegraphics[height=1.2cm, width=4.5cm,angle=10]{example-image-a} };
    \node[align=center, text width=5cm,below = 0.1cm of R6] (R6txt) %at ([yshift=-.5cm]R6.south) 
                                                                  {Industrial light beacon BR50}; 
        
    %----
    % 4-5
    \node[align=center, text width=4cm] (R4txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,2cm)}]R6.north west) 
                                                                  {Fan HJM\\HM-4500};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = -0.1cm of R4txt.north] (R4) {\includegraphics[height=3.75cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    
    \node[align=center, text width=4cm] (R5txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,2cm)}]R6.north east) 
                                                                %([shift={(3cm,0cm)}]R4txt.east) 
                                                                 {CDPR\\end-effector};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.1cm of R5txt.north] (R5) {\includegraphics[height=3.5cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (wind) at ($(R4.east)!0.45!(R5.west)$) {\includegraphics[height=1.8cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    
    \node[circ1] (C4) at ([shift={(0.75cm,3.25cm)}]R4txt.north west) {\bf 4};
    \node[circ1] (C5) at ([shift={(-0.75cm,3.25cm)}]R5txt.north east) {\bf 5};
    
    \node[circ1] (C6) at ([shift={(0cm,-6.4cm)}]C4) {\bf 6};  % <-----
    %----
    % 3
    \node[align=center, text width=8cm] (R3txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,10.3cm)}]R6txt.north) 
                                                            {Industrial servomotor\\AM 8112};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.cm of R3txt.north] (R3) {\includegraphics[height=2.75cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    \node[circ1] (C3) at ([shift={(0cm,5cm)}]C4) {\bf 3};
    %----
    % 2
    \node[align=center, text width=8cm] (R2txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,4.3cm)}]R3txt.north) 
                                                            {Industrial controller\\CX 5130};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.1cm of R2txt.north] (R2) {\includegraphics[height=2.2cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    \node[circ1] (C2) at ([shift={(0cm,5cm)}]C3) {\bf 2};
    
    %----
    % 1
    \node[align=center, text width=8cm] (R1txt) at ([shift={(-0.cm,4.3cm)}]R2txt.north) 
                                                            {Intel RealSense D435i};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above = 0.1cm of R1txt.north] (R1) {\includegraphics[height=2.5cm, ]{example-image-a} };
    \node[circ1] (C1) at ([shift={(0cm,5cm)}]C2) {\bf 1};
    
    %------------------------------------
    \node[draw, vhilit, fit= (C1) (R1txt) (C5) (R6txt) (C6)] (DPART) {};
    %------------------------------------
    %------------------------------------
    
    \path let \p1 = (DPART.north), 
                \p2=(DPART.south),
                \n1={veclen(\y1,\y2)},
                \n2={\n1-.8mm}
    in
        node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
        anchor=east] (TOT)
        at (DPART.west)  {\includegraphics[height=\n2]{example-image-a} } ;
    
    
    \begin{scope}[x={(TOT.south east)},y={(TOT.north west)}]
        \node[circ1] at (1.1,0.5) {\bf 1};
        \node[circ1] at (1.115,0.08) {\bf 3};
        \node[circ1] at (0.65,0.55) {\bf 5};
        \node[circ1] at (-0.3,0.2) {\bf 6};
        \node[circ1] at (-0.01,0.725) {\bf 4};
    \end{scope}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you. I would like the separation of inner space. If I use the real photo with the inner space still have to adjust \n2={\n1-.8mm+1.35em}. If I make the right trim (e.g. 4cm) then the image align right and leave a white space at its left.

Ask another question on this subject, specifying that it follows this one.
